# Azure policy definition to allow the access to a VM via Bastion only for users of a specific user group

Tags: azure, azure-policy, azure-security

I have a VM which can be accessed via bastion. I want to write a policy definition to deny the access if the user is NOT a member of a specific user group. I started with the following part, but not sure how to continue with the user and user group part in the definition.

```
{
      "mode": "All",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts"
            },
            {
              "field": "name",
              "in": [
                "test-vm-bastion"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "deny"
        }
      },
      "parameters": {}
    }
```

I need to correct/complete the definition for the given purpos mentioned up.

Answer (score 0):

> To allow the access to a VM via Bastion only for users of a specific user group.

Azure Policy does not directly evaluate **user or group** membership for access control, Instead, you can use Azure **RBAC** to restrict to connections to **VM** via `Bastion`

Create a custom **RBAC** role with below permissions.

- **Reader role** on the `Azure virtual machine`.
- **Reader role** on the `NIC` of the `Azure virtual machine`.
- **Reader role** on the `Azure Bastion` resource.
- **Virtual Machine Administrator Login** or **Virtual Machine User Login role**, if you’re using the `Azure AD sign-in` method.

Go to **Resource Group Where your VM resides > Access control (IAM) > Add  > Create a custom role**

You can use the following `JSON` code to create a custom role that allows connection to a VM via Bastion. Simply add the code in the `JSON` section when creating a `custom role`.

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "roleName": "Bastion Connect role",
        "description": "This role will only be able to connect to the VM if Microsoft Enterprise Login is enabled on the Azure VM.",
        "assignableScopes": [
            "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-2b83a074c23f/resourceGroups/v-venkal-Mindtree"
        ],
        "permissions": [
            {
                "actions": [
                     "*/read",
                    "Microsoft.HybridConnectivity/endpoints/listCredentials/action"
                ],
                "notActions": [],
                "dataActions": [
                    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/login/action",
                    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/loginAsAdmin/action",
                    "Microsoft.HybridCompute/machines/login/action",
                    "Microsoft.HybridCompute/machines/loginAsAdmin/action"
                ],
                "notDataActions": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

Once you create a `Custom Role`, you can assign it to an **Azure AD Group** at the **VM** level by navigating to below steps.

**Go to your Azure VM > Access control (IAM) > Add > Access control (IAM) >  Add role assignment**

[image]

[image]

After assigning the `custom role` to an `Azure AD group`, only the members of that group will be able to access the **VM** through `Bastion`.

**Reference:**  [Connect to a VM using Bastion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/connect-vm-native-client-windows)

[Required roles to connect to the VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/connect-vm-native-client-windows#required-roles)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have a problem that there are other inherited roles from the subscription scope which also have access to the VM. Thus, the access to the VM will not be limited to the custom role you suggested. How can I disable other inherited roles without removing them on the subscription role?

Comment: If roles are inherited through a subscription, it becomes challenging to restrict access to the resource, as Azure Policy may not be effective in this scenario. Alternatively, you can create a conditional access policy to restrict access to the cloud application (Azure Portal) for users who are not part of the group

Comment: Actually, this is what I have been trying to do since the beginning. I want to restrict access for users who are not part of the group. How can I create such a policy?

Comment: That will block all management access, including the Azure portal, as we can't specifically block only Azure Bastion